# How to create metroLog application in windows 8 application?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-8

I have to create log files for a Windows 8 application that is querying Twitter API by linqtotwitter nuGet.

I red this link and others but didn't find a response.

https://github.com/mbrit/MetroLog/blob/master/Samples/ConsoleSample/Program.cs

I tried to do that, but I can't see where the file is created.
I tried nLog and log4net but they didn't work with Windows 8 applications.

Does anyone have suggestion?

How can I solve this log file problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [project wiki](https://github.com/mbrit/MetroLog/wiki) the log files are created inside `~/LocalState/MetroLogs`, i.e. inside [`ApplicationData.LocalFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx).

You can find this folder in the following location on disk: `c:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PackageName\LocalState\MetroLogs`